# Get the default contact phone number

Tags: contacts

When we dial a selected contact, the first phone number is always picked (unless another number has a default flag set in DB). How can someone get that first phone number? How are those numbers ordered?

Answer (score 3):

You can define the default number yourself:

- open the "contacts" / "people" app
- tap the contact to view it
- long-tap (i.e. tap-and-hold) the number you want to make the default, a pop-up will open
- select "make default"

Comment: May also say "Make Primary". depends on Andriod version.