# How can I change the default phone number for a contact?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, contacts

I have seen [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/39895/get-the-default-contact-phone-number) and [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/113127/how-to-delete-a-contacts-mark-as-default-selection#123622), but on my phone, a MotoG3 with Marshmallow 6.01 and what seems to be the built-in Contacts app (same version as the OS), long-tapping the number only gives Cut/Copy/Paste choices, and the extra menu has "Share" and "Lookup in Wikipedia".

Deleting the main number and adding it back made the other number the default, but there must be a better way?

Comment: What if you touch the contact once(not number) ? You tried may be it gives you a pop up with the options you are looking for.

Comment: Hmm. Actually works. I mostly tried when in "Edit" mode but it should be done when just in "Display" mode. I would swear I also tried that before, though.